# How to create a WCF service

Tags: wcf

I want to learn step by step how to create a WCF service, starting from something very simple.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check below link. The tutorial is given in very simple and easy steps - [C#.Net How To: Create a WCF Service in Visual Studio 2010](http://a1ashiish-csharp.blogspot.in/2012/01/cnet-how-to-create-wcf-web-service-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

See [this series of web casts](http://www.dasblonde.net/2007/06/24/WCFWebcastSeries.aspx) by Michelle Bustamonte.

If you are a beginner, this is one of the best sources to learn WCF.

You can also start with the book [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596101627).

Also take a look at these SO posts -

[Learning the basics of WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846107/learning-the-basics-of-wcf)

[What is the best way to learn WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416846/what-is-the-best-way-to-learn-wcf)

[Good and easy books/tutorials to learn WCF latest stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343896/good-and-easy-books-tutorials-to-learn-wcf-latest-stuff)

Comment: +1 Michelle's blogs, webcasts pertaining to WCF are excellent

Comment: I disagree, I think they're not readily accessible making them far from "excellent".

Answer (score 1):

As for resources: there's the [MSDN WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) which has everything from beginner's tutorials to articles and sample code.

Also, check out the [screen cast library up on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/wcf-screencasts.aspx) for some really useful, 10-15 minute chunks of information on just about any topic related to WCF you might be interested in.

Also very good are [The Service Station](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee532402.aspx?sdmr=servicestation&sdmi=columns) articles in MSDN magazine on various aspects of WCF - some more basic like [Serialization in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163569.aspx) or [WCF Bindings in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163394.aspx), some more advanced and esoteric - but always worth a look!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [webcast](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135) to be an excellent introduction to WCF.

I would also recommend anything by Juval Lowy, especially his book [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805489).  His website, [IDesign.net](http://www.idesign.net), has a lot of free code downloads that I find especially instructive.

Answer (score 0):

some people are just better at explaining stuff to others (MSDN and Microsoft in general are not)

Here's the [page](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/dennis/archive/2010/06/16/wcf-simple-example-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) I knew would satisfy me before I even began reading it.